D-Wave hybrid solver
I am interested in using the D-Wave CQM hybrid solver for solving the job shop problem.
I would like to get more information about the internal working of this solver but I have been
unable to find more than what can be seen in the ads.
Can you provide bibliography about this CQM hybrid solver?

This may help: https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/doc_leap_hybrid.html At the end of the page, there is a lot of another links to examples.

As the name suggests, D-Wave's hybrid solvers combine classical solvers with quantum annealers. Generally, a hybrid solver starts by decomposing an optimization problem into smaller pieces, which then are run on either a QPU or CPU or both.
Designing your own hybrid solver is relatively straightforward, as D-Wave provides an open-source framework for building them. See their Github.
If reading code is not your cup of tea, you can start with the overview of the key concepts behind hybrid solvers. The framework allows you to combine their QPU with classical solvers. The classical solvers can be from D-Wave's own library, or you can bring in your own solvers or other solvers like Gurobi or open-source OR-tools from Google.
The CQM hybrid solver is also open source, and you can see its inner workings here.

The kind of answer I needed @MonteNero
